# Able to access other user information using valid session

Tags: browser-hijacking

So, I'ma login to the website using my valid account. But there is Web API (GET) using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "parameter" that we can access without login. Some page needs to login to access it.

This is the case

Login using:

- Username
- Password

Available Page:

- **Page A** => We should log in to access it
- **Page B** => Common information page no need to log in

When I logged into the website, then I can access **Page A** but when I try to access that **Page B** (Web API) using the parameter:
example:
http://www.websiteurl.com/?name=another_username

Then I can access like common information (gender, last_login, etc of common information), after accessing that when I try to go back to **Page A** it shows *another_user* information not my information again.

I checked into cookie only have:

`PHPSESID: randomCookieValues12345678`

Questions:

- Why did it happen? and how to avoid this problem too?
- Is this against cyber rules? although this happened because of the programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capturing your own traffic would likely show what's going on, however see **caution** below.

Given your description, it sounds like the site is applying a binary authentication for the site and not a user level authentication. In short, once you are authenticated as a valid user, no other checks apply.

Sadly, this kind of mistake still happens even in places you would think would know better.

**I'll caution you on how you may go about reporting this security problem.**

> *Look, I can get anyone's information by doing this!*

May result in ***them*** coming after you for hacking

> *Hey, my data was wrong when I went back?*

A clueless question demonstrating ignorance and confusion over your own information is more likely to be received well and looked into.

It's an unfortunate reality that "*Kill the Messenger*" is still quite common.

If it's a viable option, I'd simply avoid the site.